# How to replace Symlinks with the files they point to on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, symbolic-link

I am trying to batch replace symlinks in several folders with the original files that they point to. The only solutions I've come across are Linux/Unix/Bash scripts as shown here: [Replace Symbolic Links with Files](https://superuser.com/questions/303559/replace-symbolic-links-with-files)

Right now I've been using WSL2 (Ubuntu) to handle this process.

The below code does the job wonderfully:

`for f in $(find -type l);do cp --remove-destination $(readlink $f) $f;done;`

But I really need a native windows method that accomplishes the same thing so I can invoke without opening WSL (batch processing multiple folders, etc.).

Ultimately I want a PowerShell function that handles this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks much.

Comment: `gci | ? LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink' | % { copy $_.LinkTarget $_.Directory ; rm $_.FullName }` add `-r` to `gci` if you want to do this recursive

Comment: @SimonS See this: https://i.imgur.com/XN32fpN.png

It's not replacing the symlinks with their target. Getting `Cannot overwrite the item C:\Users\futur\Desktop\We10X-special\We10X-special\status\22\battery-empty-charging.svg with itself.`

And as a bonus middle finger, it's deleting all the symlinks after processing. Any other ideas?

Comment: try adding `-force` here: `copy $_.LinkTarget $_.Directory -force` otherwise check the output of `gci | ? LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink' | select FullName, LinkTarget` - do FullName and LinkTarget have the same value?

Comment: Force didn't work. It just deleted all the symlinks. Here's the result of gci:

https://i.imgur.com/3uMVaT0.png

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$links = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Attributes ReparsePoint -Recurse
foreach ($link in $links)
{
    $source = $link.Target;
    $destination = $link.FullName;

    & cmd.exe /C del $destination /F
    & cmd.exe /C copy $source $destination /Y
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).