# List directories containing symlink

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, tree-view

I have a number large number of directories, many of which contain symbolic links to files elsewhere.

I would like to replace these links with the files as described in [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/303559/replace-symbolic-links-with-files)

However to do this I need a list of the directories containing symlinks. I know I can see them using `tree` but is there a way to get a nice neat list I could feed into a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with relative paths you can try something like:

```
find . -type l -exec dirname {} \;|sort -u
```

If you want absolute paths you can use:

```
find "$PWD" -type l -exec dirname {} \;|sort -u
```

The idea is to use `find`, searching for soft links get the directory name of these files and then get only unique names.